# Spectrum in functional-analysis and algebraic geometry

Tags: functional-analysis, algebraic-geometry, soft-question

Why do we use the notion "spectrum" both in functional-analysis and in algebraic geometry? Are there any analogies?

Comment: If $A$ is a complex $n \times n$-matrix with characteristic polynomial $\chi$, you have bijection of sets between the spectrum of $A$ and $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb C[X]/\chi$. Yet, I don't know whether this motivated any of the two names or if it is just a coincidence...

Comment: This has definitely been asked before. I would poke around MO for the thread. My recollection is that someone shot this reasoning down using quotes from the big-shots of the era. It's probably worth noting that Grothendieck started his mathematical life off as a functional analyst. It's very fun to speculate how that influenced him.

Comment: Well I misremembered. The [question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24090/what-is-so-spectral-about-spectra) was more about the usage in topology and AG. The comment by Marc Palm about Gelfand-Naimark is very good though.

Comment: Did you read the answer I wrote? Does it answer to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is that in Functional Analysis the "Spectrum" is the family of *maximal* ideals of a ring, while in Algebraic Geometry, as Grothendieck defined it, the Spectrum $Spec(A)$ of a commutative ring with unit, is defined as the space (topoogical space with the natural Zariski topology) whose points are the *prime* ideals of the ring. In particular, since all maximal ideals are prime, but not viceversa, there are in the $Spec(A)$ (a la Grothendieck), points that are *not closed*, i.e., all points represented by those ideal which are primes, but not maximal. Whereas the spectrum in Functional Analysis, all points are closed, making the topology of Gorthendieck's Spectrum $Spec(A)$ much more interesting than the topology of the Gelfand spectrum in Functional Analysis.

It was actually one of the greatest insights of Alexander Grothendieck, to realize that a good definition of the Spectrum in Algebraic Geometry had to enclose all the prime ideals and not just maximal ideals as in Functional Analysis, and so it would have been quite more general. It is important to understand that Grothendieck started his career precisely in Functional Analysis.

Comment: An interesting quote from the Serre-Tate letters book that I hadn't read in full before: "“Schemes were already in the air, though always with
restrictions on the rings involved. In February 1955, Serre mentions that the
the theory of coherent sheaves works on the spectrum of commutative rings in which every prime ideal is an intersection of maximal ideals." (So, Jacobson rings) Lots of good references in [this paper by Oort](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oort0109/AGRoots-final.pdf).

Comment: Yes, that was precisely one of Grothendieck's immense genius great realizations: to take the space of prime ideals, instead of the (more obvious choice, as explained in my answer) space of maximal ideals. The second great realization was to endow this space of a natural sheaf, the structure sheaf an not just the topological structure. Two gigantic steps, that only a genius like Grothendieck could dare to take.

Comment: In fact, there is some evidence that the set of all prime ideals was already considered by Krull in the 1930's. See p.13 of this paper by McLarty: http://www.landsburg.com/grothendieck/mclarty1.pdf

Comment: Sure. Indeed a whole section of EGA I is devoted to "Schemas de Chevalley", which are defined as the prime spectrum of a ring. This section was only in the 1st edition of EGA and was not in the second. The problem was that noboy was able to come up with anything really interesting about this notion of Spec(A) before Grothendieck, because they didn't realize that only the topological structure was not enough and to have something interesting one has to add to the definition the structure sheaf. That was Grothendieck's understanding and his own alone.

Comment: Sure, I don't dispute that you need the structure sheaf to get the theory off the ground. I just think that _Two gigantic steps, that only a genius like Grothendieck could dare to take_ is overstating the case a little when someone else had already taken one of those steps (albeit abortively). But we can agree to differ.